# Problem with Custom Reports on Magento

Tags: php, error, custom, reports, nginx

Something happen with one of the stores. When i try to open the Custom Report for the Orders, and i've got nothing. Like its listing only the column names, but nothing else. like:

```
2016-01-19T07:36:30Z 2016-01-21T09:36:49Z 14.00 12435 28800 0 0 False False Order # Purchased on Ship to Name G.T. SKU Item Category Season Gender Weight Price Status Shipping Method Payment Method Teacher Location Translate
```

And this is the reported error log from the Nginx:

```
2018/01/22 11:45:39 [error] 6855#0: *136455309 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFrontend() on boolean in www/app/code/local/Netcube/CustomReports/Helper/Data.php:388
Stack trace:
#0 www/app/code/local/Netcube/CustomReports/controllers/Adminhtml/EntityController.php(17): Netcube_CustomReports_Helper_Data->generateOrdersReport('2018-01-19 09:4...', '2018-01-22 09:4...', '0')
#1 www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Netcube_CustomReports_Adminhtml_EntityController->editAction()
#2 www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#3 www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 www/ap" while reading response header from upstream, client: 11.22.33.44, server: example.com, request: "POST /index.php/customreports-directory-admin/entity/edit/continue/0/key/c34ddb8351e8e9373a1ef6ae202497f1/ HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/tmpfs/php.sock:", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/index.php/customreports-directory-admin/entity/edit/key/c34ddb8351e8e9373a1ef6ae202497f1/"
```

I only markout the name and the ip address. The version of Magento is 1.9.1.1. It was working before, i don't really know what really happen without any touch.